# resize nodes in tikz and boxes to visualize three levels of subsets

Tags: nodes, tikz-pgf

im trying to overlap multiple nodes to visualize three levels of subsets and include some text for each subset.
Is there a way to force the fit comand to increase the padding? or is it more efficient to manually resize each box?
thanks for your support.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={align=center, inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=3mm, rounded corners}, very thick]
    \node (inner1) [draw] {text text text text text text text text};
    \node (outer) [fit=(inner1)] {};
    \coordinate (o) at ($(inner1.north)!1!(inner1.south)$);
    \draw [blue, rounded corners] (outer.north west) rectangle (outer.east |- o) node [above=5mm of inner1, anchor=center] {text text text text text text text text};
    \node (doubleouter) [fit=(outer)(inner1)] {};
    \draw [red, rounded corners] (doubleouter.north west) rectangle (doubleouter.north east |- o) node [above=15mm of inner1, anchor=center] {text text text text text text text text};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you want to achieve a dissymetrical internode separation (0 at the lower part, xmm at the upper part), this cannot be achieved directly. You need either to compute the node coordinates or to use several nodes.

Here is a solution with several nodes.

Box nodes correspond to the boxes. They have a 0pt inner ysep in such a way that they can be simply included without adding extra vertical spacing. They have though an inner xsep to have growing sizes.

Text nodes have an inner y separation to have the text properly displayed.

You must first draw the text, then the box, enclosing this text and the previous box, thanks to the fitting library.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit, calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      [
      box/.style={inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=0, draw=#1, rounded corners, very thick},
      txt/.style={align=center, inner xsep=0mm, inner ysep=3mm},
      ]

    \node[txt] (inner1 txt)  {text text text text text text text text};
    \node[box=black,fit=(inner1 txt)] (inner1 box) {} ;

    \node[txt, above=0 of inner1 box] (inner2 txt) {\ldots}  ;
    \node[box=blue,fit={(inner1 box) (inner2 txt)}] (inner2 box) {} ;

    \node[txt, above=0 of inner2 box] (inner3 txt) {text text text text text text text text}  ;
    \node[box=red,fit={(inner2 box) (inner3 txt)}] (inner3 box) {} ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Node can have only one name, therefore instead `\node[box=black,fit=(inner1 txt)] (inner1) (inner1 box) {} ;` should be `\node[box=black,fit=(inner1 txt)] (inner1 box) {};`

Comment: Right. I probably changed my mind on the way node should be named and modified the code incorrectly. Thanks for pointing out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (variation of @Alain Merigot nice solution: +1) with use of `chains`, `fit` and `positioning` library:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, 
                fit,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 1mm and 0mm,
    start chain = A going above,
FIT/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw=#1, rounded corners, ultra thick,
                          fit=#2, 
                          inner xsep=6mm, inner ysep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                          node contents={}},
     txt/.style = {minimum height=3ex, align=center, on chain=A},
                        ]
\node[txt]  {text text text text text text text text};  % A-1
\node[txt]  {\dots};  % 
\node[txt]  {text text text text text text text text};  
%
\node (f1) [FIT=black/(A-1)];
\node (f2) [FIT=blue/(f1) (A-2)];
\node (f3) [FIT=red/(f2) (A-3)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possible :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i/\L/\c in {1/A/black,2/B/red,3/C/blue}
{\def\mw{4+2*\i}
 \node (inner\i at (2,0) [draw,color=\c,thick,minimum width= \mw cm,minimum height=\i cm, align=center, text depth=\i cm, rounded corners,anchor=south] {Set $\L$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]